# Showing that a piece-wise defined sequence converges to $0$ via $\epsilon$-definition?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I wish to show if $S_n = \begin{cases}
  2e^{-n}, & \mbox{if n is even }  \\
  -\frac{3}{n},  & \mbox{if n is odd }  
\end{cases}$ then we have $S_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Does it suffice to consider the the odd/even terms of the sequence separately? e.g.

If $n$ is even, take $ N > \log(2/\epsilon)$. Then $n > N \implies n > \log(2/3) \implies |2e^{-n}|< \epsilon$

And if $n$ is odd, then take $N > -\frac{3}{\epsilon}$. Then $n> N \implies n > -\frac{3}{\epsilon} \implies |-\frac{3}{n}| < \epsilon$.

Comment: You need to be more careful. $N$ is supposed to be an (positive) integer and neither of your choices are integers and one of them is even negative!

Comment: Your first $N$ is not a function of $\epsilon$ so something is wrong.

Comment: In general, the trick in this kind of situation is to find $N_1$ for the first situation and $N_2$ for the second situation and then set $N = \max(N_1,N_2)$.  Then if $n > N$ then $n > N_1$ and $n > N_2$ so everything works.

Comment: But there has to be just *one* N for each given $\epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @LoveTooNap29 Instead of saying "take $N= \ldots $" would it be correct to say "take $N > \ldots $"?

Comment: @JairTaylor Thanks, that's neat. Is there a situation where you have to take the $\min(N_1, N_2)$ instead?

Comment: @user537566 yes, but make sure if you take $N>x$ it is such that $x$ depends on $\epsilon$ at most, as others commented. You can also take $N=\lceil x \rceil$ if you feel like it.

Comment: @user537566 I doubt it; in proving converging of sequences you want to make sure $N$ is big enough, you don't worry if it is too big.  But, maybe in some other context you would take the $\min$.

Answer (score 1):

That's right. Also notice that for $n$ being odd, we must have $$N>{3\over \epsilon}$$not $N>-{3\over \epsilon}$. The general $N$ for both even and odd terms then would become$$N>\max\left\{{3\over \epsilon}  , \log{2\over \epsilon} \right\}$$